# Нужно ли получать Token? и как?

Tags: java, google-authenticator

Подскажите, как правильно сделать аутентификацию юзера, допустим при `Google LogIn` ?

Я не сильно в этом пока разобрался, поэтому прошу помочь понять, как правильно должно работать процесс `LogIn`-а.

Получается, когда я делаю логин с помощью гугла, то я отправляю запрос, гугл его подтверждает и возвращает ответ с конкретным юзером, я беру `id` этого юзера, его почту, имя и отправляю на сервер. Сервер проводит подтверждение этого юзера и возвращает обратно все данные по нему...

Но, что будет, если кто-то украл почту юзера, имя и id и отправил на сервер, и получил данные, получается не хорошо...

Если я правильно понял, то нужно от гугла получать `Token`, его тоже отправлять на сервер, сервер когда его получит обратиться тоже в гугл и проверит тот или не тот токен, и тогда все будет работать как нужно.

Но как в таком случае получить `Token`?

Подскажите, насколько я в правильном направлении?

Как вообще должен проходить процесс аутентификации с сервером?

**ПРАВКА**

Когда проходит аутентификация через гугл, то при нажатии на кнопку гугл предоставляет доступ к использованию своего апи.. Но ведь это никак не связано с аутентификацией на моем сервере...

Получается я получаю аутентификацию на гугле и не понятно как ее правильно связать с аутенфикацей на моем сервере?

**ПРАВКА 2.0**

```
public void initGoogleLogIn() {
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = getGoogleSignInOptions();
    mGoogleApiClient = getGoogleApiClient(gso);
    SignInButton btnSignIn = (SignInButton) authorizationActivity.findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_in);
    btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(listener);
}

@NonNull
private GoogleSignInOptions getGoogleSignInOptions() {
    return new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(context.getResources().getString(R.string.server_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

}

@NonNull
private GoogleApiClient getGoogleApiClient(GoogleSignInOptions gso) {
    return new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
            .enableAutoManage(authorizationActivity, listenerConnection)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
//      facebook
    FacebookImplementation.getCallbackManager()
            .onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

//      google
    if (requestCode == States.GOOGLE_SIGNIN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(result);
    }
}

private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    Logger.log(ActivityAuthorization.class, ""+ result.getStatus().toString(), Logger.ERROR);

    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        Logger.log(GoogleImplementation.class, "User is connecting by Google LogIn", Logger.ERROR);

        // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
        
    }else {
        Logger.log(GoogleImplementation.class, "!!!!!!!!!!!!", Logger.ERROR);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В приложении подключаете либу гугла для авторизации. Данные пользователя нужно получать, насколько я знаю, от API Google Plus, который является хранилищем данных пользователей.

1. пользователь нажимает кнопку "авторизоваться", у него промигивают окна (авторизация на гугле, выдача разрешений) и он возвращается в приложение.
2. приложение получает от либы данные пользователя и access_token.
3. передаете access_token на свой сервер. Никакие данные пользователя получать от либы и передавать на сервер не требуется, им нельзя будет доверять.
4. используя access_token, на сервере получаете от гугла необходимые данные пользователя и производите необходимые действия по авторизации/регистрации, после чего отвечаете приложению.

Возможно, access_token, полученный в приложении, так просто нельзя будет использовать с сервера (с другого ip). Как правило, это решается добавлением некоего параметра к запросу авторизации.

Получение access_token выполняется примерно таким образом:

```
accessToken = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(
    getApplicationContext(),
    mPlusClient.getAccountName(), "oauth2:"
        + Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN + " "
        + Scopes.PLUS_PROFILE+" https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read");
```

Здесь хорошие примеры кода по получению токена: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23759529/android-how-to-get-google-plus-access-token

Comment: Кстати интересно, я не обратил внимания первый раз. Получается если я правильно понял, то не клиент с гугла получает свои данные и отправляет для подтверждения их на сервер, а получается, что все что должен отправить клиент на сервер это токен, а уже по этому токену сервер сам все получит и отправит обратно клиенту, верно?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko если под клиентом вы имеете ввиду приложение - то да, все верно. Точнее, приложение может получить от гугловых сервисов как данные пользователя, так и токен. Но данные пользователя нам, в данном случае, не нужны, так как сервер им не сможет доверять. Но не понял насчет "отправит обратно клиенту"? Зачем с сервера обратно клиенту отправлять данные пользователя? Вам же нужно провести авторизацию на сервере, или я что-то неверно понял?

Comment: Да, все верно нужно провести авторизацию, но вот пример, я открываю приложения делаю логин с гуглом и прохожу авторизацию, но где приложение должно взять допустим мою фотографию профиля, имя и т.д. (для отображения в боковом меню как пример)? Сервер после проверки токена должен выслать обратно или на стороне клиента с гугл аккаунта их получить?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko да как вам удобнее. Если у вас есть система пользователей, хранимая на сервере и аватары у них - очевидно, должен присылать сервер всю инфу о юзере. Если у вас на сервере ничего про юзера не хранится - можно и напрямую из соцсети.

Comment: а можете обьяснить я не могу понять как получать  время действия токен ид? Вот я получаю токен ид при регистрации через гугл, но там нет никакого метода которым можно получить время его действия...

Comment: Если я все правильно понимаю, то данные по времени жизни токена и refresh токена должны получаться на сервере и отправляться обратно клиенту... Клиент на сервер отправляет только tokenId и все?

Answer (score 4):

В вашем случае без токена никак нельзя

Для начала прочтите эту [статью](https://habrahabr.ru/company/mailru/blog/115163/)

А потом загляните в [Google OAuth 2.0 песочницу](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/)

Вам многое станет понятно сразу

Для подробного изучения рекомендую прочесть документ [технический стандарт OAuth 2.0](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749)

Comment: Спасибо! Действительно стало понятнее... Но теперь возник вопрос, может вы знает как ответить? Когда проходит аутентификация через гугл, то при нажатии на кнопку гугл предоставляет доступ к использованию своего апи.. Но ведь это никак не связано с аутентификацией на моем сервере...

Получается я получаю аутентификацию на гугле и не понятно как ее правильно связать с аутинфикацей на моем сервере?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/

Comment: А можете пожалуйста обьяснить согласно статьи ссылка на которую указана в вашем ответе, так написано, что нужно получать `expiry` этого токен ид... Но я не могу понять как получать это время действия? Вот я получаю токен ид при регистрации через гугл, но там нет никакого метода которым можно получить время действия...

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko после обмена authorisation code на токены  используя пример google (https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token), при успешном ответе прийдет JSON массив схожий с этим `{
  "access_token":"1/fFAGRNJru1FTz70BzhT3Zg",
  "expires_in":3920,
  "token_type":"Bearer"
}` где параметр `expires_in` это и есть время действия access токена. Внимательно изучите https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#handlingtheresponse

Comment: Если я все правильно понимаю, то данные по времени жизни токена и `refresh` токена должны получаться на сервере и отправляться обратно клиенту... Клиент на сервер отправляет только `tokenId` и все?

Comment: в этом случае POST запрос (POST request) должен содержать
code код авторизации возвращенный из первоначального запроса
client_id полученный из консоли API.
client_secret полученный из консоли API.
redirect_uri cсылка для перенаправления
grant_type Как обозначено в спецификации OAuth2, поле должно содержать значение authorization_code

Читайте внимательно последнюю ссылку

Comment: Мне кажется мы не совсем правильно понимаем друг друга) Вы мне скинули ссылку в которой описано сторона сервера и веб приложения их взаимодействие... А мой вопрос о андроид приложении (добавил код в вопрос)... Куда мне там нужно поставить `POST запрос (POST request) должен содержать code код авторизации возвращенный из первоначального запроса client_id полученный из консоли API. client_secret полученный из консоли API` ? И как в итоге получить этот `refresh token` ? Вот об этом мой вопрос))